# Android share facebook lite

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm having trouble using the new facebook share (LITE)

I am using the sdk facebook as follows, to share an image:

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)) {
                                SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                        .setBitmap(obterBitmap()) // obtem imagem
                                        .build();
                                SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                        .addPhoto(photo)
                                        .build();
                                shareDialog.show(content);
                            }
```

The problem is that does not work with facebook lite, some hint of how to solve?

Comment: Please use english on StackOverflow - it helps to understand the question by broader audience.

Comment: Is this spelled correctly?  .setBitmap(obterBitmap())

Comment: Yes, it works in standard app facebook, but not on facebook lite.

Comment: More information: What doesn't work? What happens? What version of Android SDK (4.x)? What version of FB Lite?